# Looking for .NET Math method that will zero a negative integer

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, math

Similar in concept to Math.Abs() - I'm looking for a function that when given a positive integer will return the same integer. If given a negative, will return zero.

So:

```
f(3) = 3
f(0) = 0
f(-3) = 0
```

Yes, this is simple enough to write on my own but I'm wondering if the .NET Math class already has this built in or if the same can be achieved by cleverly chaining a few Math.* calls?

Comment: Duh. Thanks guys. I obviously don't spend enough time in Math.*

Answer (score 131, accepted):

It's called `Math.Max`:

```
Math.Max(0, x)
```

Comment: Simple and clean :)

Answer (score 36):

This seems to be what you want, no?

```
Math.Max(0, num);
```

Answer (score 18):

I think

```
Math.Max(0, x)
```

is what you want.

Answer (score 5):

Given 32-bit signed integer `num`, the following expression returns zero if it is negative, or the original unchanged value otherwise:

`(~num >> 31) & num`

This operation is sometimes called ***clamping***; values less than zero are **clamped** to zero. To effect clamping on `num` itself, use the following statement:

`num &= ~num >> 31;`

---

**Explanation**

Only positive integers (and zero) have `0` for their **sign bit**, which is the leftmost, or "most-significant bit" (a.ka., "[MSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering#Most_significant_bit)"). Let's consider the 32-bit case. Since bit positions are numbered from left-to-right starting with 0, the sign bit is "bit 31".  By flipping this bit and then propagating it to each of the 31 other bit positions, you get a result where either:

- for positive values and zero, all bits are set (`0xFFFFFFFF`, `-1`), or
- for negative values, all bits are cleared (`0x00000000`, `0`).

By [masking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)) the original value with this result, you have zeroed out the value, but only if it was negative originally.

**Remarks**

1. Since `&` (bitwise-**`AND`**) has very low precedence in **C#**, you will usually have to surround these expressions with outer parentheses:

   ```
   ((~num >> 31) & num)
   ```
2. If `num` is ***unsigned*** (e.g., `uint ui`), you must use a cast to make sure the shift is signed. This is called a **right-arithmetic shift**, and it ensures that the MSB is duplicated into each rightwards shifted position:

   ```
   ((int)~ui >> 31) & ui
   ```
3. For 64-bit values, shift by 63 bits instead of 31:

   ```
   /* signed */     long v;      (~v >> 63) & v

   /* unsigned */   ulong ul;    ((long)~ul >> 63) & ul
   ```
4. As shown, you must use the `~` (bitwise-**`NOT`**) operator to flip the sign bit. If you attempt to use "unary minus" `-` instead, you will get the wrong answer for value `0x80000000` because this is one of exactly two integer values that is *not affected by applying the minus sign to it*. Bitwise-**`NOT`**, on the other hand, is guaranteed to flip every bit of any/every value. (The other value that can't be negated is zero, which for this particular problem happens to work out correctly either way)
5. If you're in a rush, here are some tested extension methods, ready to copy/paste.

   ```
   public static int Clamp0(this int v) => v & ~v >> 31;
   public static long Clamp0(this long v) => v & ~v >> 63;
   ```
6. One hazard with using the methods shown in (5.) is that there's no error or warning if the caller forgets to assign the return value to anything. In **C#7** you can define ***by-reference extension methods*** which allow for ***in-situ*** mutation of value-types. Such methods help avoid the aforementioned problem since they can (and accordingly always should) be declared as returning `void`:

   ```
   public static void RefClamp0(this ref int v) => v &= ~v >> 31;
   public static void RefClamp0(this ref long v) => v &= ~v >> 63;
   //     'void' ──^          'ref' ──^                ^── result assigned by callee
   ```

   Call-site examples for the preceding *by-ref* extension method on `int`:

   ```
   int x = -999;
   x.RefClamp0();        // CORRECT, clamps the value of 'x' in-situ; now x == 0

   // x = x.RefClamp0(); // NO -- 'void' return enforces correct by-ref usage
                         // CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'int'

   // -999.RefClamp0();  // NO -- compiler errors:
                         // CS1510: A ref or out value must be an assignable variable
                         // CS0201: Only [expressions] can be used as a statement
   ```

**Learn more about non-branching code!**

This code example provided above is one of the simplest [bit-twiddling](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) examples which demonstrates  [branchless code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_(computer_science)#Performance_problems_with_branch_instructions). If you're not familiar with it, the term generally refers to a wide variety of micro-optimization techniques which try to minimize conditional branches in user code, in order to reduce misprediction stalls in the CPU pipeline.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Math.Max is the way to go, but this would work too... ;)

```
(num + Math.Abs(num)) / 2
```

Comment: If you're ok with potential overflow on the addition

Comment: +1 Interesting take! It's the type answer i expected initially.

Answer (score 3):

Math.Max is best, but without Math and in VB

```
(num >= 0) * -num
```